# Wordpress migration on Ubuntu with no or minimal downtime

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress, migration

As part of a customer project I have to migrate a wordpress (WP) installation from one digital ocean droplet to a different one.

I consider to execute tests of the target system AFTER update of the system software (Apache, Wordpress, PHP, mysql), system hardening and data migration (file system, db) by redirecting the requests from the original system to the target system temporarily (301 redirect).

I am concerned with regard to the generation of data inconsistencies between the two systems during the tests (or formulating the opposite: whether it is possible to migrate the system so that (possible) data on file system and in the db is identical in both systems). If we do not exclude access of users (apart from the tester) to the web site during testing (which should be avoided according to the project owner), IMHO it could be possible that there are requests that change data in either the file system and/or the (mysql-)database which would lead to the aforementioned inconsitencies.

My questions:

1. Does WP (or WP plugins) store data in the file system at all upon http requests?
2. Is there a straightforward way to avoid those inconsistencies while the original system is online (straightforward means: no measures allowed which presume implementations entailing a high effort like HA-clusters and similar)?